# Print characters from a string (first character; then first and second; then first, second, and third)

Tags: java, eclipse, string, loops

In java, if I wanted to print out characters from a string in this order:

```
String str = "abcdefg";
System.out.println("a");
System.out.println("ab");
System.out.println("abc");
System.out.println("abcd");
System.out.println("abcde");
System.out.println("abcdef");
System.out.println("abcdefg");
```

Which algorithm can I use to do this?

Comment: where is the issue? Have you tried anything?

Comment: a simple loop would be enough along with String#subString()

Comment: I haven't tried but I'm having a hard time thinking about how to implement it.

Comment: @user2360087 Start by taking a look at the [`String` Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and see what methods are available that might give you information you could use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, one would be to use a `StringBuilder` for example...

```
String str = "abcdefg";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append(c);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

This simply takes each character in turn and appends it to the `StringBuilder` and prints the result...as an example ;)

Comment: @TheLostMind Well, it's just one of a number of possible approaches ;)

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to do it with a list instead of a string.

Comment: @user2360087 Right, because that was the original question :P

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code you need:

```
String str = "abcdefg";
for (int i =1 ;i<str.length();i++){
  System.out.println(str.substring(0,i));
}


For all List elements:

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("abcdefg");
    list.add("hijklm");
    for (String str : list) {
      for (int i =1 ;i<str.length();i++){
        System.out.println(str.substring(0,i));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach +1

Comment: is there anything similar to substring for arraylists?

Comment: @user2360087 A quick look at the [`ArrayList` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-) reveals the answer

Comment: how can I do this with every element of a list rather than every character of a string?